# Lets delete "What is Java used for these days?"

Tags: discussion, status-completed, specific-question

https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/q/17053/40980 was asked in 2010 (Java 6 was still in active development). The information in it is quite dated (J2EE isn't a thing anymore - incidentally, it was Java 6 that got rid of J2SE and J2EE). Android is refered to as 'new'.  Some of the answers are no more than one sentence anecdotes:

> It's still being used in the Academia quite a bit ...

> The company I work for uses J2EE and uses it for web development too. I know SAP has integrated a Java interface that can be used instead of ABAP.

Without a significant amount of updating, the answers are becoming more and more dated and serve as worse and worse examples for others.

While there's a lot of views on it, it really isn't providing any up to date information.  Looking at the [anonymous feedback](http://data.stackexchange.com/programmers/query/220020/qa-anon-feedback?QuestionId=17053) votes on the question and its answers, downvotes are often outweighing the upvotes (the question received 1.2k anon upvotes, and 1.6k anon downvotes).

With its lack of current information, and vastly outdated information the question provides no utility to anyone who finds it via search.

Is there any reason to keep this question around?

Comment: Only needs 4 more votes to delete.

Comment: 48K views vs troublesome answers and negative anon feedback, an interesting case

Comment: Now only 3 more delete votes.

Answer (score 6):

The question is heavily (but not primarily) opinion-based and certainly too broad.

The answers are rambling, outdated, and many are low-quality. Several provide examples of individual projects that use Java, which is a bit too specific to be of much use. Q: "What are cars used for these days?" A: "Well my cousin is a cab driver." Sure, that technically answers the question, but is useless information.

The bigger issue is "what value does this question and its answers provide?" As far as I can tell it serves one of several purposes:

1. Fuel for the language flame wars.
2. Answers the questions "what language or technology should I take up next" and "recommend an off-site resource such as a language" (Java, in this case).
3. [Pros and cons](https://softwareengineering.meta.stackexchange.com/q/6758/22815) of Java.

In no way does this question bring measurable benefit to the site.

If there is any useful content in any of the answers, it belongs in the [Java tag wiki](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/tags/java/info) which probably has enough useful information as-is.