# Would a question about when to use (and not use) subdomains be on topic?

Tags: discussion

I was going to use subdomains to allow routing to various categories on a site, but someone advised against that approach (but didn't say why).

For example, routes like

```
baseball.example.com
basketball.example.com
football.example.com
# etc
```

I am therefore curious as to when one should and should not use subdomains.

Would such a question be on topic here?

Answer (score 6):

No.

1. Use of subdomains is generally unrelated to software engineering issues, and is usually more about marketing concerns such as search engine optimization. There also are technical and organizational reasons for and against subdomains (e.g. regarding the same-origin policy) which are tangential to software engineering as a whole, but still not in scope for this site.
2. Aside from these problems regarding our site scope, open-ended questions like “what are the pros and cons” are typically too broad to be answered effectively.

Related meta posts:

- [Why was my question closed as "Too Broad?"](https://softwareengineering.meta.stackexchange.com/a/6490/)
- [What is the problem with “Pros and Cons”?](https://softwareengineering.meta.stackexchange.com/q/6758)