# What's not focused about my idiom-adoption question?

Tags: discussion, closed-questions, close-reasons

I've recently asked:

[Pros and cons of using the "die" idiom in C++?](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/439501/pros-and-cons-of-using-the-die-idiom-in-c)

and the question was closed as unfocused. It has an answer and some comments, but no comment explaining why it is supposedly unfocused, or even in what aspect/sense it is unfocused. Meta members' help is requested in elucidating, so that I can perhaps focus it to the detractors' satisfaction.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What is the problem with "Pros and Cons"?](https://softwareengineering.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/6758/what-is-the-problem-with-pros-and-cons)

Comment: @gnat: No, why?

Answer (score 2):

Your question's body was surely focussed enough to be answerable, but the original title made it look like a poll, and some of our members here apparently lack the instinct to distinguish between acceptable and unacceptable "Pros and Cons" questions.  Polls are usually classified by our community as "needs more focus" (formerly known as "too broad"), which is a classic close reason.

The solution is not to argue with them, it is to remove the unfortunate buzzwords from the title, and vote for reopening (or ask a mod for a second pair of eyes). This is what I did. Thanks to Thomas Owens who reopened the question.

Comment: Well, to close, one needs to give a reason, and the reason given was it not being focused enough. But ok.

Comment: @einpoklum: see my edit.