# Is this place right to ask about specific clean code practices?

Tags: discussion, on-topic-definition

I've been focusing on clean code lately and I'd like to know if this is the right place to upload code that I believe can improve in this matter. Obviously well written and documented code.

If this is possible, how should this code be? Can it be specific code that solves a problem or should I make it abstract. I ask this because I know if I post something too abstract, I may get downvoted as "too broad".

If this is not the place, is there another inside Stack or another webpage for this?

Comment: You may want to look at the [Code Review](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) SE site and see if it might be a better fit for the type of feedback you're looking for. Compare with [what's on-topic here](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic).

Comment: Ok, that is what I was looking for. Post it as the answer so I can check it. Thanks.

Comment: see also: [Are Design Review questions on-topic?](https://softwareengineering.meta.stackexchange.com/a/6504/31260)