# Is the software engineering site suitable for asking software architecture?

Tags: discussion

I know Software Engineering Site and StackOverflow both can ask programme technical questions.

But which is better for asking software architecture questions and Design modes?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Generally, yes. But without seeing your specific question, it's not possible to tell if your question falls within our guidelines. You may want to check out our [guidelines for design review questions](https://softwareengineering.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/6502/are-design-review-questions-on-topic).