# How make a question about feedback for an university exercises?

Tags: discussion, feature-request

I would like ask for feedback in exercises which has a little extensive statement. More specifically there are use cases exercises which have a business description that can be 1 or two Word pages but resolution might no be so extensive. My idea it's provide my resolution diagram and make question about puntual parts of exercise so I'm not sure if theses large statements are aceptable in questions. What do you think? Can you give me some advice for this kind of question?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Even if you can [make the question on-topic](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) and follow [our guidance for asking a good question](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask) (also consider [our guidance for design review questions](https://softwareengineering.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/6502/are-design-review-questions-on-topic)), I'm not entirely sure that you should. It's highly unlikely that the people answering the questions are familiar with your coursework or what the expectations of the instructor are. Most of us are professional software developers. In a course, the best course of action for the real world (which is probably what you'd be able to get from us) may not be what the instructor is looking for as a correct answer.

When it comes to course work, I would recommend asking your instructor or a tutoring/mentoring center at your university. These people would be more likely to give you the information that you need to do well in the course and understand more context.