# Where/how to ask about API design?

Tags: support

I thought it was appropriate to ask on this site about how best to design library APIs, but my most recent question about that just got closed [How to support parametrization/interpolation bindings in your API?](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/q/446000/224123) I don't even see what rule is broken.

Is there a site on the network where it is allowed? Or, how could I rework the question to make it suitable here?

Comment: The question wasn't closed as off-topic, but rather as too broad. You might get the question reopened if you make the question more specific and narrow the scope.

Comment: @user16217248 why is too broad?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Are Design Review questions on-topic?](https://softwareengineering.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/6502/are-design-review-questions-on-topic)

Comment: @gnat apparently not, bc the consensus there seems to be that my original question should not have been closed

Comment: @theonlygusti: please read the answer to that older question again: Thomas Owens wrote: *However, the problem is how broad they are. My concern for this type of question is that most of them may be more suited to a discussion environment.*. In your own question, you wrote *"What would be either the most established, or the most well-liked, or the most robust solution for this kind of API design in Java?"*  - this is exactly the kind of invitation to a discussion Thomas Owens' was describing and which our community typically closes as "too broad/needs more focus".

Comment: @DocBrown are there any examples of library API design questions on this site that have not been closed? The one linked to in the older question just reads exactly the same (even worse according to these metrics) than my own question to me

Comment: @theonlygusti: older questions from 2014 and before often stay open for historical reasons, even if they would be closed today. This site has gone through a renaming and refocussing process since then. 10 years ago, when the site was called "Programmers.SE", the accepted scope was much broader. And for examples, you may look through questions tagged with api and design: https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/api+design