# What is wrong with the given question?

Tags: discussion

I am struggling for a couple of times to put a good question for discussion. I need help to understand what is wrong with the [this](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/q/361416/198298) questions?

Comment: I didn't vote on that question yet, but at a cursory glance you might want to give a read to http://idownvotedbecau.se/noattempt/

Comment: @gnat read that. AFAIK the audience and intent of the SE is different from SO, the intent is to understand concepts which would help in writing good code. Asking for correcting the given code is better for codereview imo.

Comment: well if you prefer guidance specifically tailored for this site here is one: [Why is research important?](https://softwareengineering.meta.stackexchange.com/a/6560/31260)

Comment: @gnat I think there is some serious confusion between community members, I updated my question with my findings and one the member literally blamed me for some `trick` and deleted his answer. Also, I don't know for what reasons I am receiving continuous downvote. Please keep in mind I have been a member for a long time and have asked well received questions in the past. I think you need to chime in.

Comment: this is not a confusion but well known thing - after the question is answered the options to edit it get narrower, specifically editors need to keep an eye on answers and avoid invalidating these

Comment: @gnat so, I ideally I should ask new question then?

Comment: if you can't edit into better shape without invalidating answers, probably yes. Though in this particular case since the answer is deleted you aren't bound by that, at least until someone else posts an answer

Comment: @CodeYogi: What might be tripping you up is that the StackExchange Q&A format is *not* suited for discussions. There is no room for a back-and-forth exchange between users, but only for questions that can be answered with a few paragraphs of text.