# criteria to judge if question is well framed or not

Tags: discussion

I would like to understand the criteria to judge if question if well formed or not. For example, recent question posted [here](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/365737/is-call-site-compiler-generated-auto-code)
received three down votes. I still think question is well defined and precise though. It might also happen that people who saw question and down-voted might not have that deep exposure to concept asked in question, isn't it ? After all it needs 125 reputation for any one being privileged to down-vote question. Sometime question might need expert intervention. I am not complaining but honestly trying to understand how this really plays well.

Shouldn't down-voting action make "provide comment" compulsory ?

Not sure how many down vote for this question :-P

Comment: Well, this question is IMHO very broad, but maybe this older meta question can give you some answers: https://softwareengineering.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/6483/why-was-my-question-closed-or-down-voted

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why is research important?](https://softwareengineering.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/6559/why-is-research-important)