# Would a question along the lines of 'what is the link between one programming language and another' be on topic?

Tags: discussion

I am curious to know the relationship between a language I program in and another, older, language which influenced it. There is no specific aspect I'm interested in, it's more that I am interested to learn how the language I came to know was influenced by the one that came before it.

Would such a question be on topic here?

In case it matters, the languages are R and Lisp.

Answer (score 4):

I think the issue with such kind of question wouldn't be topicality. If you just ask it literally, I would expect the question to be closed as too broad (a.k.a. "needs more focus"). Askers on this site are expected to show serious research effort before they post a question, tell what they found and why it did not meet they needs (see ["Why is research important?"](https://softwareengineering.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/6559/why-is-research-important) for the reasons behind this). Our community does not like it when someone just tries to pass a research task to them, especially a research task one could have done by themselves using Wikipedia and Google.

What you could try instead is to start with the available sources about the origins of R (for example, [using Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/R_(programming_language)) and the resources mentioned there), then check what you can find out about the connection to Lisp. When asking your question, you should tell us why you think there is a connection between the two languages, and where you see a missing link. That still isn't a guarantee the question to survive, but it should increase the chances for the question to get accepted.